# Differential equations (second edition) - William E. Boyce & Richard C. Diprima (#$31$, page $142$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> In many physical problems, non-homogeneous term may differ from one
>   time interval to another. By example, determine the solution $y =  \phi(t)$ at
>
> $$y'' + y =  \begin{cases} 
>      t      & \quad \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \pi \\
>     \pi e^{\pi - t}  & \quad \text{if } t > \pi \\   \end{cases} $$ with the initial contitions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0)=1$
>
> Suppose also that $y$ and $y'$ are continuous at $t = \pi$. **Hint :**
>   First, resolve the problem at initial value for $t \leq \pi$. After,
>   resolve for $t > \pi$ in determining the constantes of the last
>   solution and in supposing the continuity at $t = \pi$

I obtain as solution

$$y(t) =  \begin{cases} 
    t      & \quad \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \pi \\
    \pi e^{\pi - t}  & \quad \text{if } t > \pi \\   \end{cases} $$

but the solution of the book is

$$y(t) =  \begin{cases} 
    t      & \quad \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \pi \\
   -(1+\frac{\pi}{2}) \sin(t) - (\frac{\pi}{2}) \cos(t) + \frac{\pi}{2} e^{\pi - t}  & \quad \text{if } t > \pi \\   \end{cases} $$

I'm trying for quite a while to resolve my problem, but without result. Does someone could explain to me how could I correct my solution?

This is the exercise #$28$, page $178$ of this [link](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjl5-DygfHKAhXJLB4KHRc0CXMQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdebian.fmi.uni-sofia.bg%2F~horozov%2FDifferentialEquations%2Fboyce-diPrima.pdf&v6u=https%3A%2F%2Fs-v6exp1-ds.metric.gstatic.com%2Fgen_204%3Fip%3D132.204.185.38%26ts%3D1455238504749797%26auth%3Dy7vzi7pphlj3mnqaau2t5u5vamapp3o5%26rndm%3D0.6685080297702547&v6s=2&v6t=7508&usg=AFQjCNE0gk6U8Bs0qpIQS-NNd4ElOhaWlQ&bvm=bv.114195076,d.dmo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous part of the equation has the solution
$$
A\sin t+B\cos t
$$
Let's use [operator method](http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/calculus/differential/the-d-operator.php) to find particular solution and then the complete solution.

> $0\le t\le\pi$

$$
{1\over D^2+1}t=(1-D^2+D^4-\cdots)t=t\\
$$
In this case $y(0)=0$ yields $B=0$ and then $y'(0)=1$ yields $A=0$. So the complete solution is $$y=t$$

> $t>\pi$

$$
{1\over D^2+1}\pi e^{\pi-t}=\pi e^{\pi-t}{1\over(-1)^2+1}={\pi\over2}e^{\pi-t}
$$
Using the continuity of $y,y'$ we have $y(\pi)=\pi,y'(\pi)=1$. Here $y(\pi)=\pi$ yields $B={\pi\over2}$ and then $y'(\pi)=1$ yields $A=-(1+{\pi\over2})$. So the complete solution is
$$
y=-(1+{\pi\over2})\sin t+{\pi\over2}\cos t+{\pi\over2}e^{\pi-t}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the characteristic equation, we get the general solution
$$y_c=c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t$$

For the first part, we try the particular solution
$$y_p=At+B$$

Since you got your first part correctly, I think you know how to get 
$$y=t, 0\leq t\leq \pi$$

Now for the second interval, you still have the general solution
$$y_c=c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t$$

For the particular solution, since right hand side is $\pi e^{\pi} e^{-t}$, we try $Ae^{-t}$:
$$y_p=Ae^{-t}$$
This gives 
$$y_p''=Ae^{-t}$$

Plugging these into the second part of the differential equation gives us
$$y_p''+y_p=2Ae^{-t}=\pi e^{\pi-t}$$
So $A=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\pi}$.

Now we still don't know what are $c_1$ and $c_2$. Since $y$ and $y'$ have to be continuous at $\pi$, we set $y(\pi)=\pi$, and $y'(\pi)=1$ for
$$y=c_1\cos t+c_2\sin t+\frac{\pi}{2}e^{\pi-t}$$

which you can see easily comes from the first part of the solution. This will give us the desired solution.

Comment: Instead of taking $y_p = A e^{\pi-t}$, you took $y_p = A e^{-t}$, but is it make a difference?  Could you explain to me why you evaluated at $\pi$ instead of $0$ as desired by the problem? Is it because of the compositions of function?

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad: It does not make a difference since $e^{\pi-t}=e^{\pi}e^{-t}$ where $e^{\pi}$ is just a constant that can be treated as absorbed in $A$ or not. We evaluate it at $\pi$ since the problem says the function $y, y'$ are continuous at $\pi$. So we need to make sure they assume the same values at $\pi$ from the left and from the right.

Comment: Ok, but you use the fact that $y(\pi) = \pi $ and $y'(\pi)=1$ as if it was the initial value. Could you explain in more details why you did that?

Comment: ...and you use them to find $c_1$ and $c_2$ for the related function.

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad: That is because I am looking for $c_1$ and $c_2$ in the second interval $t>\pi$. We already found that $c_1=c_2=0$ in the first interval $0\leq t\leq \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong because

1. It is not a solution of the differential equation. It's always a good idea to check your solution by plugging it in to the differential equation and seeing if the two sides are equal.
2. Its derivative is not continuous at $t=\pi$.